# Purpose For, Of

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

- 1 He has no intention for marriage.
- 2 He has no intention of marriage.

These two sentences are good English and have the same meaning.

In this [PDF](http://www.uniontwp.com/2012Minutes/Minutes%2008-13-12%20Board%20Meeting.pdf) I read:

> A review of the grading permit showed that the permit had not been modified from its original ***purpose** which was ***for*** a minimum use driveway for a mobile home.

Now, since *intention* means almost the same thing as *purpose*, could these sentences be okay?

- 3 He has no purpose for marriage.
- 4 He has no purpose of marriage.

Comment: Don't confuse semantics & grammar this way. It doesn't matter that word A means the same as word B; the usage rules that govern each word may be quite different: they aren't dependent on meaning. I don't know where in the Anglophone world those first two sentences are "good English", but certainly not in the USA, where they're **not idiomatic**, as Sven Yargs says. "Intention" & "purpose" are only sometimes synonymous, but not in those two sentences: the 1st means _He doesn't plan to marry_, the 2nd, _He has no use for marriage_. Your PDF sentence has a different structure from the others.

Comment: I suggested  ["The purpose of..." versus "the purpose for..." — which one is proper?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/the-purpose-of-versus-the-purpose-for-which-one-is-proper) as a possible duplicate, but that question is about   “purpose for” *vs*  “purpose of”, rather than about   “purpose” *vs*  “intention”.

Comment: My 7th grade English teacher told us that "*ominous* means *threatening* but that doesn't mean I can say, 'The bully was ominous that small boy on the playground.'"

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the relevant idioms are elsewhere in the English-speaking world, but in the United States, none of these four sentences would be used by a native English speaker. The closest I can get to a sentence that combines *intention* and *marriage* in the sense suggested above is "He has no intentions with regard to marriage"—but the more normal way to express that idea would be something along the lines of "He has no intention of getting married" or (to preserve the noun *marriage*) "He has no interest in marriage."

I can't think of any sentence that combines *purpose* and *marriage* as intended here in a normal-sounding way.

Comment: Could the ".... ***purpose which was for*** a minimum use drive way" example in my question about poorly written?

Comment: @fifem: It's missing a comma after _purpose_, but otherwise it's semantically fine. It's just not similar in structure to your example sentences and the usage rules that govern it are quite different.

Comment: Also, I think it's important to note Jon Hanna's comment regarding the dissimilarity of _intention_ and _purpose_. In some contexts the terms seem almost interchangeable, but in others, either exigencies of idiomatic usage or differences in the definitions themselves show up markedly. That's what I think happens in the context of the four original sentences about marriage.

Answer (score 2):

> He has no intention of marriage.

Fine.

> He has no intention for marriage.

We're told that God has intentions for marriage, and society has intentions for marriage. These intentions are allegedly why marriage exists.

One might have an intention for marriage as in "his only intention for the marriage was to get a visa".

> Now, because "intention" almost means the same thing as "purpose"

They are related words, but they're far from perfect synonyms. Your purpose is your reason, your intention is your hoped for outcome. Even in cases that fit the overlap, would use them differently:

> The last time I was in a church, it was for the purpose of getting married.
>
> The last time I was in a church, it was with the intention of getting married.

But your use is not in this overlap, I have several intentions. I do things for various purposes. A tool *has* a purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that the sense you have in mind is what would be expressed most simply as

> He does not intend to marry.

Sentence 1 will not bear this sense: to *have an intention **for*** something means to intend to do something ***with*** it. *Thank you for the award. My intention for it is to fund a new research project*. *He has intentions for his daughter: he wants to see that she gets a professional education.*

Sentence 2 is acceptable, but rather old-fashioned. Today we would be more likely to say

> He has no intention ***of marrying***.

*Purpose* and *intention* mean somewhat different things: your *intention* is, generally, what you are trying to do, while your *purpose* is what you hope to achieve by doing it. Accordingly, you can't really substitute *purpose* for *intention* in the same context. And to speak of someone having *no purpose* generally means exactly that—

> He has ***no purpose*** in life.
>   He has ***no purpose*** in courting her, he’s just fooling around for lack of anything better to do.

When we want to deny a specific purpose, it will usually be in the context of specific actions. For instance, you observe that a man is paying court to a woman and say

> [He is courting Sarah, but] marriage is ***not his purpose***. [He's just trying to make Polly jealous.]
>   [He is courting Sarah, but] ***his purpose is not*** to marry her. [He wants to learn her father's secrets.] 
>   [He is courting Sarah, but] ***not with the purpose of*** marriage. [He intends to steal her diamonds.]

You can also say

> [He is courting Sarah, but] has ***no purpose to*** marry her. [The cad!]

But this, again, is very old-fashioned.

As for the sentence you quote:

> ... the permit had not been modified from its original purpose which was ***for*** a minimum use driveway ...

This is an awkward sentence; but the ***for*** really belongs not to *purpose* but to *permit*. The writer has compressed two different ways of expressing the idea:

> The original permit was ***for*** a minimum use driveway.
>    The *purpose* of the original permit was to license construction of a minimum use driveway.

Comment: I am confused with `...to intend to do something with it. ` Is it like `I intend to continue my job with honour.`?

Comment: @Mistu4u  See my edit.